# How to write a SQL DB Backup script with format: Demo_YYYYMMDD_XX.bak

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, backup

how to write a daily backup script with unique name format: Demo_YYYYMMDD_XX
where XX is an incremental number based on the backup history.

Example as below.

1. 1st Backup: Demo_20170704_01.bak
2. 2nd Backup: Demo_20170704_02.bak
3. 3rd Backup: Demo_20170704_03.bak

XX will increase +1 every time the backup process is run on the same day and same folder(path).

Managed to come out with the script below. Any improvement needed? thanks

```
DECLARE @path VARCHAR(500) 
DECLARE @name VARCHAR(500) 
DECLARE @pathwithname VARCHAR(500) 
DECLARE @time DATETIME 
DECLARE @year VARCHAR(4) 
DECLARE @month VARCHAR(2) 
DECLARE @day VARCHAR(2) 
DECLARE @counter varchar(10)

SET @path = 'C:\Backup Path\' 

SELECT @time = GETDATE() 
SELECT @year = (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), DATEPART(yy, @time))) 
SELECT @month = (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), FORMAT(DATEPART(mm,@time),'00'))) 
SELECT @day = (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), FORMAT(DATEPART(dd,@time),'00'))) 
SELECT @counter = (
select format(count(A.database_name),'000')
from msdb.dbo.backupset A join msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily B 
on A.media_set_id = B.media_set_id
where A.database_name = 'Demo' 
and (select convert(date,A.backup_start_date, 120))  = (select convert(date,getdate(), 120))
)

SELECT @name ='Demo' + '_' + @year + @month + @day + '_' + @counter
SET @pathwithname = @path + @name + '.bak' 

BACKUP DATABASE Demo 
TO DISK = @pathwithname WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT, SKIP, REWIND, NOUNLOAD, STATS = 10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two choices.

- list files in directory that match your pattern (date), count and increment
- keep a count of how many backups you make each day (increment)

Since you have a database and are backing up that database, why not just do the latter? And record your daily backups to a table that has,

```
create table backups (
    dbback DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE()
   ,dbname varchar(99) NOT NULL
   ,name   varchar(99) NOT NULL
   ,index  int NOT NULL
   ,primary key(db,backdb)
) ;
```

You can record the pair (db,backdb) to record entries for multiple databases (dbname, dbback).

```
WITH t as ( select (backups.index+1) as nextnum
from backups where dbname = 'database_name' and dbback = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
union select 1 as nextnum from dual )
insert into backups (dbback,dbname,name,index)
values (CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE),'database_name','yourname',t.nextnum) ;
```

Note that by using union you ensure that you get the base (first) row in the temporary table